# JOINing two tables in MySQL when multiple rows in one table relate to one row in another

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `module_config` and `module_settings`. The latter contains rows with default values, and the former contains rows which are to override the default values.

I have created the tables with some test rows in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad4eb .

Here are my specifications:

1) I want to provide a list of `gid`s. For example, provide `100`, `24`, `48`, `50`.
2) I want the query to return a row for each setting (given in `module_settings`) for each `gid`. It should ignore any `module_settings` row where `module_settings.gid_specific` is equal to `0`.
3) `value` will be equal to the corresponding value given in `module_config` if that row exists, otherwise the `initial` value given in `module_settings`.

With the above fiddle, I would like something that can return the following (for the input of the above 4 `gid` values):

```
| mid----- | gid | name-------- | value |
| currency | 100 | hand_default | 12--- |
| currency | 24- | hand_default | 17--- |
| currency | 48- | hand_default | 29--- |
| currency | 50- | hand_default | 0---- |
| currency | 100 | bank_default | 0---- |
| currency | 24- | bank_default | 0---- |
| currency | 48- | bank_default | 0---- |
| currency | 50- | bank_default | 0---- |
```

So, it first finds all rows in `module_settings` where `gid_specific` is equal to 1. These rows are distinct by having a unique combination of `mid` and `name`. After that, it returns a row for each of these settings for each `gid`. So for the `module_setting` row where `mid` equals `currency` and `name` equals `hand_default`, it will return 4 rows, one for each `gid` of `100`, `24`, `48` and `50`. The only thing left to do is decide what value to associate with this row. If there exists a row in `module_config` where `module_config.sid` equals `module_settings.id` and `module_config.gid` is the `gid` in question, then use the value given by `module_config.value`, otherwise use the default value given by `module_settings.initial`.

As you can see, I've formulated it in my head, but I just can't get my head around putting this into a query statement. If anyone can shed some light I would be really grateful.

Comment: For the data you provided, where `gid` = `50` would come from?

Comment: In the PHP code, there will be an array of `gid` values (which will have been pulled from another table in the db).

Comment: Please look at your fiddle and verify that your output can be obtained from the fiddle's tables.

Comment: Do you mean because there isn't a row with `gid`=`50`? I purposely excluded this from the table as the PHP code may supply `gid` values which have not been inputted yet into the `module_config` table, in which case it should use the default value given by `module_settings.initial`.

Comment: If what I am asking is then not possible, would it instead be possible to output a row for each default value (given by `module_settings`) and then a row for everything in the `module_config` table? That way I could parse the final table (above) with some PHP.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a [`CROSS JOIN`](http://www.sqlguides.com/sql_cross_join.php) that represents the full Cartesian product of the two tables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56854/discussion-between-pm-77-1-and-keir-simmons).

Comment: Remind me, how do the two tables relate again?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Teradata SQL. I am sure if you try, you can find equivalent syntax for the SQL.

I have used a tbl3 in addition to your two tables as the source of gid that you say is coming from a PHP array.

Step 1: Cross Join of **module_settings** and **module_config**

```
SELECT mid,gid,name, b.value1
FROM IBB_APP.module_settings a, IBB_APP.module_config b
WHERE gid_specific = 1;
```

This results is

```
mid                                       gid  name                              value1
--------------------------------  -----------  --------------------------------  ----------
currency                                  100  hand_default                      12
currency                                   24  hand_default                      17
currency                                   48  hand_default                      29
currency                                  100  bank_default                      12
currency                                   24  bank_default                      17
currency                                   48  bank_default                      29
```

Step 2. Including the **tbl3** which gives the gid = 50 too.

```
SELECT mid,c.gid,name, 
    CASE WHEN b.gid = c.gid THEN b.value1
         WHEN b.gid IS NULL THEN a.initial1 END AS value1
FROM IBB_APP.module_settings a, IBB_APP.module_config b
RIGHT OUTER JOIN IBB_APP.tbl3 c ON (b.gid = c.gid)
WHERE gid_specific = 1
ORDER BY name,c.gid;
```

The result is

```
mid                                       gid  name                              value1
--------------------------------  -----------  --------------------------------  ----------
currency                                   24  bank_default                      17
currency                                   48  bank_default                      29
currency                                   50  bank_default                      0
currency                                  100  bank_default                      12
currency                                   24  hand_default                      17
currency                                   48  hand_default                      29
currency                                   50  hand_default                      0
currency                                  100  hand_default                      12
```

I hope this helps and that I understood your requirements correctly.

Comment: Hooray for RIGHT JOIN